# working with files in dynamic web project

Tags: java, file, io

I am working on a dynamic web project.
On submit button click (present on my form)I want to create a new file and put some data inside.

I have written only these two lines and I am getting failure to create file

```
try{
     File file = new File("C:/database.txt");
     file.createNewFile();
}catch(Exception e){
     return "error in creating file";
}
```

If I run the enire code in normal java class everything works fine. Why so?

Answer (score 0):

Your web project is working on application server. The web application can manage files, which are on that server. Other files are not accessible. (of course localhost server is on your computer, but that it's path is not "C:/", so you can't write there). You can find the path of your server running this code (it also create a test file):

```
String pathWhereYouFindYourFile = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(pathWhereYouFindYourFile);
File f = new File("test.txt");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks @Piotr does that mean that I need something like file uploading etc?

Comment: No, you don't need. This code above creates new file (as you wanted), and before creating file prints on screen the path, where this file will be created.